# How can I fold streaming data?

Tags: haskell, frp

I'm trying to implement functional reactive streams in Haskell. I have this rather simple definition:

```
data Observer a = Observer { next :: a -> IO () }
data Stream a = Stream { subscribe :: Observer a -> IO () }

instance Functor Stream where
    fmap = mapStream

mapStream :: (a -> b) -> Stream a -> Stream b
mapStream f Stream{ subscribe=s } = Stream {
        subscribe = \Observer{ next=n } -> s Observer{ next = \a -> n $ f a }
    }

 fromArray :: [a] -> Stream a
 fromArray arr = Stream {
        subscribe = \Observer{ next=n } -> forM_ arr n
    }
```

This works well for simple operators like `fmap` above. My question is how would I implement `foldStream` for this? I can't change values, so I will have to recursively call `foldStream` with a new seed value. But I have no clue how to do this in this context. Is this even possible with my simple definition or do I need something different? Thanks.

Comment: What type would `foldStream` have?

Comment: Presumably `foldStream :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Stream a -> Stream b`

Comment: just like fold for Arrays: `foldStream :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Stream a -> Stream b`

Answer (score 3):

`foldStream` keeps track of state. You'll have to put that state somewhere, like in an [`IORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html).

```
import Data.IORef

foldStream :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Stream a -> Stream b
foldStream f z source = Stream $ \observer -> do
    ref <- newIORef z
    subscribe source $ Observer $ \a -> do
        b <- readIORef ref
        let b' = f a b
        writeIORef ref b'
        next observer b'
```

Comment: Thanks, I already guessed that i would have to use the state monad or something similar. Just wanted to be sure that there is not a clever way to use recursion for this